# Analogs of Lambek grammar that can encode structural ambiguity?

Tags: syntax, grammar-formalism

My understanding (mistaken, see below) is that in basic lambek/categorial grammar, the basic objects are strings. Does anyone know of variants where one can have multiple trees for the same string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "basic" Lambek/categorial grammar, or by "basic objects". But you can certainly have multiple trees for the same string, at least in a bidirectional categorial grammar, i.e. a categorial grammar with two concatenation operations (\ and /).

**A bidirectional CG:**

1. The basic categories are n (for noun) and s (for sentence).
2. If A and B are categories, then (A\B) and (A/B) are categories.
3. If *a* is an expression of category A, and *b* is an expression of category A\B, then *ab* is an expression of category B.
4. If *a* is an expression of category A/B, and *b* is an expression of category B, then *ab* is an expression of category A.

**Lexicon:**

- *men* and *women* both have category n.
- *old* has category n/n.
- *and* has category (n\n)/n.

The expression (string) *old men and women* now has two different parses: (i) [old men] and women, and (ii) old [men and women].

```
[old men] and women:

    old       men           and          women
    n/n        n          (n\n)/n          n
    -------------
          |
       old men              and          women
          n               (n\n)/n          n
                          --------------------
                                    |
       old men                  and women
          n                        n\n
       ----------------------------------
                       |
               old men and women
                       n


old [men and women]:

    old       men           and          women
    n/n        n          (n\n)/n          n
                          --------------------
                                    |
    old       men               and women
    n/n        n                   n\n
              ---------------------------
                          |
    old             men and women
    n/n                   n
    -----------------------------
                  |
          old men and women
                  n
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To clarify, my question concerns whether in the deductive system presented by lambek, the 2 terms of type n/s that you have constructed above are equal.

Comment: It seems they are not, though.

Comment: In a natural deduction system (or sequent calculus) for a Lambek grammar, you would have two proofs of "old men and women", with both proofs resulting in the same syntactic category but differing in semantics. What I gave was a categorial grammar derivation, but the idea is the same in a Lambek grammar proof. See Carpenter 1998 *Type-Logical Semantics* (ch. 5 in particular) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the Combinatory Categorial Grammar, type-raising X->T/(T\X) yields trivially ambiguous derivations such as:

```
  X        Y\X
---------------<
       Y
```

vs

```
  X        Y\X
------->T
Y/(Y\X)
-------------->
     Y
```

While this seems counterproductive, type-raising is invoked to allow a category to become a functor over a functor (see 'Argument Cluster Coordination' in https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1011/L107/clark-lecture3.pdf)